# Display image in fluid (typo3)

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

Most likely a simple question, but I can't find any solution to this:

I'm working with fluid to setup a form. This works kinda well for now.

```
<f:form.uploads property="feuser.image">
```

takes care of the upload.

What I actually want is, to display the current image to the user, so I expect some output like this:

```
<img src="MyPic.jpg">
```

There is no `<f:form.image>` or something similar. However, for test-purposes, I tried this:

```
<f:form.textfield property="feuser.image">
```

and it does output the name of my file. However, I need just the plain string (or image-wrapper) to display it.

I also tried `<f:image src="/uploads/pics/{feuser.image}" />` but that didn't do the trick either. This results in an error:

So, even though it makes no sense to have something like form:image, how can I just display it?

> Supplied file object type TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Folder must be File or FileReference

Any ideas?

Comment: Which TYPO3-version do you use? Try to use `<f:image image="{feuser.image}"/>`

Comment: debug your variable like <f:debug>{feuser}</f:debug>, if you get string in image variable then you can use with path. Otherwise might be you upload your image using FAL then <f:image image="{object.image}" or <f:image src="{object.image.uid}" debug and see what you get